# Ffmpeg wipe diagonal transiton with audio concat

Tags: ffmpeg, transitions

[How to create “diagonal wipe” effect in FFmpeg?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24608/how-to-create-diagonal-wipe-effect-in-ffmpeg/24616#24616?newreg=1c0bdf6bd6ec4e4ea14dec86fcc2a93c)

This question has an answer, however the answer does not concat the audios of videos. How can I fix it ?

```
ffmpeg -i old.mp4 -i new.mp4 -filter_complex
   "[1]format=yuva444p,
       geq=lum='p(X,Y)':
       a='st(1,(1+W/H/TN)*H/D);if(lt(W-X,((ld(1)*T-Y)/(ld(1)*T))*ld(1)*T*TN),p(X,Y),0)':
       enable='lte(t,D)',setpts=PTS+D/TB[new];
    [0:v][new]overlay" wipe.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [acrossfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#acrossfade) filter.

```
...
[0:v][new]overlay;
[0]atrim=0:T+D[a0];[a0][1:a]acrossfade=d=D"
```

`D` like in the original command is the duration of the wipe. `T` is the time at which the wipe starts.